# How do I modify advanced MP3 metadata on Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, filesystems, metadata, xattr

I want to strip/change some extended attributes from some mp3 files that I have, but cannot seem to find any way how.

I used `mdls` to list out the full metadata of a file, and get a number of items beyond the average metadata, such as `kMDItemComment` and `kMDItemAudioEncodingApplication` (these are a couple that I'd like to delete).

However, trying to use the `xattr` command does not work. Simply using `xattr filePath` returns no list of attributes, which it does with other file types. When I try changing it anyway with a `xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemComment foo/bar/fileName.mp3`, I get an output of "No such xattr: com.apple.metadata:kMDItemComment"

Why aren't any of the attributes accessible through xattr? Are there other commands or freeware I can download to successfully access and change these properties of the files? Thanks in advance!

Comment: While I'm not that familiar with the Mac OS, it looks like `xattr` affects only Mac extended attributes, data which is part of the underlying OS.  `ItemComment` and `AudioEncodingApplication` sound like they might be data in the ID3 information embedded in the file.

Comment: @StarGeek You were absolutely right, it turns out all the fields I was looking for are just ID3 tags from later versions. I struggled to find a tool that would even let me edit them, as they are not the typical tags most people care about, but alas I found one and everything is fixed. Thank you!

Comment: @jmglynn Which tool did you find that allowed you to edit these attributes on mp3 files? I'm looking for a similar solution for some other file types.

Comment: @MaxWell Hey, unfortunately I don't remember the exact program I downloaded to do so back then, but there should be any number of freeware desktop apps or even browser based web apps that will let you edit ID3 tags with a quick google search. 

You mentioned you're interested in different file types, but are you still looking to edit ID3 tags on non-mp3 music/video files? If so, give https://www.mp3tag.de/en/ a look. 

I've since started writing scripts to programmatically edit ID3 tags in Python using the [eyeD3](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library